# CPQ learning resources available?

Tags: trailhead, cpq, steelbrick

It seems Salesforce has released almost no resources on CPQ on trailhead after its acquisition. Old Steelbrick Community pages are gone and it seems there's only documentation pages on Salesforce Help.

CPQ seems great but I'm having difficulty finding resources to learn after spinning up a dev org.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to partner portal then you can find the resources in the private group `Salesforce CPQ Enablement - GDC`.

All the Steelbrick Community pages have been transformed to [Getting Started with Salesforce CPQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_get_started.htm&type=5)

There are few trailheads are available for CPQ

- [Salesforce CPQ Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sf_cpq)
- [Salesforce CPQ Features](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/salesforce-cpq-features)

Answer (score 0):

I used below documents to learn CPQ myself. You can refer them.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_get_started.htm&type=5

https://community.steelbrick.com/t5/Prices-Discounts-Knowledge-Base/Additional-Discount-Unit-Overview/ta-p/3267